How to cite an author response on OpenReview?
I am discussing papers A and B in a paper that I'm writing. Since paper B is more recent than paper A and both propose methods to address the same problem, I hoped to find sufficient benchmarks between the two, especially since paper A is a very prominent method in the area. However, the comparisons between both methods shown on paper B are very scarce, and not much can be drawn from them.
I found the OpenReview for paper B and this concern was raised by reviewers, which prompted the authors to reply with more benchmarks, where generally the method in paper A was actually superior.
Since I am using paper A as a benchmark in my own research, I wanted to refer to this OpenReview response by the authors of paper B to support my choice to not include their method as a benchmark.
I know that it's usually not a good idea to reference a web page, but how else can I refer to these results that apparently aren't available anywhere else?

I don't know about what would be an appropriate reference citation format for this, but you'll want to archive the web page at the Internet Archive -- paste the page's URL where "Save Page Now" appears at Wayback Machine's front web page.

I do not know what citation format you work with, but book reviews are occasionally cited, probably Chomsky (1959) is the most famous. Could that form a basis for your citation?

@AzorAhai-him- I'm not sure I understand your suggestion - what could form a basis for my citation?

@SaucyGoat The format for citing a review of a published book, which has fields for the authors of the review, and the reviewed item.

@AzorAhai-him- I see, thank you for the suggestion. I'm using BibTeX, which I don't think has that option. Looking at its standard fields as well, it doesn't seem like there's a fit for an interaction on OpenReview

@SaucyGoat Well, BibTeX is not a citation format, it's a method of storing information. I use APA.
